# What is the "main file" property when doing bower init?

Tags: bower

What is the use of property **main file** when you run bower init? I have been looking and many people says that it currently has no purpose.

Is that true? Bower's documentation doesn't explain it either.

Comment: There seems to be others also confused by this. For example the writer of this bower tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/meet-bower-a-package-manager-for-the-web/

Comment: It appears that the definition of the `main` property is currently in question and being debated in an open issue on the bower github repo. Look here for the current proposed definitions and the discussion: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/935

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to the [Bower.io documentation](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#main)

> main
>
> Recommended Type: String or Array of String
>
> The primary acting files necessary to use your package. While Bower
>   does not directly use these files, they are listed with the
>   commands bower list --json andbower list --paths, so they can be used
>   by build tools.
>
> Preprocessor files like CoffeeScript should be compiled.Do not include
>   minified files.Filenames should not be versioned (Bad:
>   package.1.1.0.js; Good: package.js).

I think it's more for the package management, and build tools like Grunt and Brunch. For example, Bootstrap's `bower.json` looks like :

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "version": "3.0.3",
  "main": [
    "./dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "./dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "_config.yml",
    "CNAME",
    "composer.json",
    "CONTRIBUTING.md",
    "docs",
    "js/tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.9.0"
  }
}
```

When I build in Brunch, it pulls these files from my `bower_components` folder in my `public` folder.

Comment: What "documentation"?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The documentation doesn't clarify the role of "The primary endpoints of your package." You've stated the relevance of main to Brunch, but not how it relates to Bower.

Comment: I think the point I was trying to make, is that the main files are utilized in several build tools in regards to "these are the files my bower package intends to distribute." It's still a tad ambiguous to it's true intent.

Comment: The anchor of the documentation link is dead. See @Vivian Spencer's answer for an update.

Answer (score 9):

According to Bower's JSON Specification (https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#main), the "main" property is used to list the files primarily used in the project. The files listed are not actually used by Bower in any way, they are apparently there for the purpose of being used by other build tools.

Here is the official specification:

> #### main
>
> *Recommended*
>   Type: `String` or `Array` of `String`
>
> The primary acting files necessary to use your package. While Bower does not directly use these files, they are listed with the commands `bower list --json` and `bower list --paths`, so they can be used by build tools.
>
> - Preprocessor files like CoffeeScript should be compiled.
> - Do not include minified files.
> - Filenames should not be versioned (Bad: package.1.1.0.js; Good: package.js).

Comment: Some libraries just won't work without main files listed, wiredep to be the perfect example.

Comment: @kboom i might have the issue connected to what you are saying: for example pdf.js-viewer's css file wont copy using main-bower-files, should i put it in main inside bower.json ? If yes, do I actually have to provide the whole path for each file? thanks!